# Dynamic volume provisioning folder per pod in a volume?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, provisioning, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

What I am aiming for is a folder(pod name) per pod created inside of a volume using a volumeClaimsTemplate in a StatefulSet.

An example would be:

- PersistentVolume = "/data"
- Pods:

  - pod-0 = "/data/pod-0"
  - pod-1 = "/data/pod-1"

I am struggling with getting the replicas to create new folders for themselves. Any help with how to do this would be grateful.

Comment: could you tell the use case or what is it that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @tarunkhosla I kind of explained the use case in the question? I don't understand what more information I can give, I would like the StatefulSet to create a folder in the volume for each pod based on the replica amount.

Comment: You explained what do you want but you haven`t explained what is the use and what is the goal here. Can you give more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `volumeClaimTemplates` is a list of claims that pods are allowed to
> reference. The StatefulSet controller is responsible for mapping
> network identities to claims in a way that maintains the identity of a
> pod. Every claim in this list must have at least one matching (by
> name) volumeMount in one container in the template. A claim in this
> list takes precedence over any volumes in the template, with the same
> name.

This means that with `volumeClaimTemplates` you can request the PVC from the storage class dynamically.

If we use this `yaml` as an example:

```
volumeClaimTemplates: 
  - metadata: 
      name: www
    spec: 
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources: 
        requests: 
          storage: 1Gi
```

Once you deploy your pods you notice that your pods are being created and `PVC` is requested during the creation. `PVC` is name in the following convention:

`volumeClaimTemplate` name + `Pod-name` + `Ordinal-number`

So if you take above yaml as an example you will receive three PVC (assuming 3 replicas):

```
NAME        STATUS      VOLUME      
www-web-0   Bound       pvc-12d77135...
www-web-1   Bound       pvc-08724947...
www-web-2   Bound       pvc-50ac9f96
```

It's worth mentioning that `Persistent Volume Claims` represent the exclusive usage of a Persistent Volume by a particular Pod.
This means that if we look into the volumes individually we find that each is assign to a particular pod:

```
➜ ~ pwd
/tmp/hostpath-provisioner/pvc-08724947...
➜ ~ ls 
web-1
➜ ~ pwd
/tmp/hostpath-provisioner/pvc-50ac9f96...
➜ ~ ls 
web-2
```

---

While testing this I did achieve your goal but I had to create `persistentvolumes` manually and they had to point towards the same local path:

```
 local:
    path: /home/docker/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - minikube
```

This combined with `subPathExpr` mounted the directories named after the pods into the specified path.

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: www
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      subPathExpr: $(NAME)
    env:
      - name: NAME
        valueFrom: 
          fieldRef:
             fieldPath: metadata.name
```

And the result of this (`web` was the name of the deployment):

```
➜ ~ pwd
/home/docker/data
➜ ~ pwd
web-0  web-1  web-2
```

Here`s more information how  [subpath with expanded env variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables) works.

> Use the `subPathExpr` field to construct `subPath` directory names from Downward API environment variables. This feature requires the `VolumeSubpathEnvExpansion`  [feature gate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) to be enabled. It is enabled by default starting with Kubernetes 1.15. The `subPath` and `subPathExpr` properties are mutually exclusive.

Let me know if you have any questions.